# Moving player with touch Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm creating this mobile game in unity3D when were u tap the screen the player moves from position like in the game "RUSH". Now my problem is is that my player quickly moves from position and back when I touch and also keeps swapping positions when I hold the screen. Can someone help me?

```
private Vector3 targetPos;
public float Xincrement;

public float speed;

void Update()
{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(targetPos, transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (touch.tapCount == 1)
        {
            if (transform.position.x <= 1 && transform.position.x >= 0)
            {
                targetPos = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
                
            }
            else if (transform.position.x <= 0 && transform.position.x >= -1)
            {
                targetPos = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 0):

Touch have phases and you must check the phase `Touch.Began`. And also if you won't utilize multiple touches loop is unnecessary. Just get initial touch like:
`Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);` But i will just add touch phase part into our code:

```
void Update()
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(targetPos, transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            if (touch.tapCount == 1 && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                if (transform.position.x <= 1 && transform.position.x >= 0)
                {
                    targetPos = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
                    
                }
                else if (transform.position.x <= 0 && transform.position.x >= -1)
                {
                    targetPos = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```